# pandas groupby concatination based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like below, and I am trying to join the names, when the class is non empty,

```
Name   class score
kumar   ""    ""
ram     10    14
ravi    ""    ""
tej     ""    ""
om      12    15
```

my desired output is,

```
Name      class score
kumarram    10    14
ravitejom   12    15
```

I tried groupby class, and adding as a new series but the length is not matching,

```
my code:
    df['g1'] = df['class'].ne("").cumsum()
    df.loc[df["class"].ne(""), "Name"] = df.groupby("g1").apply(lambda x: " ".join(x["Name"].values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to find blocks with `cumsum` on negate condition. Here however, you can reverse the series before cumsum, so blocks are count from bottom up:

```
blocks = df['score'].ne('""')[::-1].cumsum()
df.groupby(blocks).agg({
    'Name':''.join,
    'class':'last',
    'score':'last'
})
```

Output:

```
            Name class score
score                       
1      ravitejom    12    15
2       kumarram    10    14
```